# Output of Powershell file in Jenkins Console Output

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a PowerShell script, **NuGetPack.ps1** as following:

```
$path = $args[0]
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | 
Foreach-Object {
   Write-Output nuget pack $_.FullName 
   -IncludeReferencedProjects 
   -properties configuration=release -outputdirectory NugetPackages
}
```

This file is being called in the Jenkins Declarative Pipeline as follows:

```
stage("NuGet Pack"){
        steps{
            script{
                def path = ".\\$projectDir\\src\\**\\**\\**\\*.nuspec"
                powershell(
                    script: "powershell -executionPolicy RemoteSigned -File .\\'Powershell Scripts'\\NuGetPack.ps1 $path")
            }
        }
    }
```

Issue: I am not getting the logs/output generated by the Powershell script file in the Console Output of the Jenkins pipeline. The console output is blank for the stage defined in the Jenkins file.

[Jenkins Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BteF.png)

Can anyone please help me in figuring out how to get the output/log in Jenkins Console Output as I am getting while running that script in Powershell?